# google compute engine- Roles in Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using this URL to get all the roles inside a project, but all i am seeing is 2 custom roles which i created. Other than these 2 custom roles there are 5 google accounts with OrgAdministrator and other roles. Those are not showing up. Is there any other API which i can use to get all the roles in project.

GET https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/roles

Answer (score 0):

`https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/roles` will give you access to the custom roles that you have set up for your project.

Is there any specific reason why you need to use an API to get all the roles in the project?

You can view the list of GCP IAM roles available for the project by going to the `Cloud Console -> IAM & admin -> IAM -> Roles` page. The list also includes the custom roles that you have set up.

Each GCP product has a set of roles available and this is documented in [1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) for Compute Engine and [2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) for Cloud Storage respectively.
You can see a programmatic example of using IAM roles with Cloud Storage buckets in [3](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#storage-add-bucket-iam-java).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL you provided you were using the [IAM API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.roles/list) and you were getting a result similar to:

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "name": "projects/PROJECTID/roles/CustomRole",
      "title": "CUSTOMROLENAME",
      "description": "",
      "etag": "BwVR17ixlds="
    }
  ]
}
```

I understand you want to know use an API to get the same the information you see when you access to Cloud Console -> IAM & Admin -> IAM -> Roles.
The API you can use is Cloud Resource Manager API and call the [projects.getIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy) method. You can give it a [try here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy) by adding your projectID in the resource field and clicking on 'EXECUTE' and you'll get a result like this:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "etag": "BwVmNKKwGt4=",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:xxxxxxxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/owner",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:xxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com",
        "user:xxxx@yyyy.zzz"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```